# Does the possibility of linear coordinate changes imply that the manifold is Euclidean?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> **Question.** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold admitting an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ (i.e. a collection of coordinate charts that covers the whole manifold) with the following property:
>
> for every pair $(U, \mathbf{x}),\ (U', \mathbf{x}')\in \mathcal{A}$, the transition function $$\mathbf{x'}\circ\mathbf{x}^{-1}\colon \mathbf{x}(U\cap U')\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbf{x}'(U\cap U')\subset\mathbb{R}^n $$ is (the restriction of) an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto itself.
>
> Is $M$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Motivation for this conjecture comes from the fact that in such a manifold one can define a Riemannian inner product in exactly the same way as one does in Euclidean space: 
$$\text{if }\mathbf{v}=v^\alpha\partial_\alpha,\ \mathbf{w}=w^\beta\partial_\beta,\quad \text{then } g(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w})=\sum_\alpha v^\alpha w^\alpha.$$
This definition is well posed because it is independent of the chosen coordinate chart in the atlas $\mathcal{A}$. The Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ is flat and locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I don't know if this extends to a *global* diffeomorphism, though.

---

> **Secondary question.** What if the transition functions $\mathbf{x}'\circ\mathbf{x}^{-1}$ are merely affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto itself?

In this case, the previous assignment for a Riemannian metric $g$ is ill-posed. However, one can still define a flat affine connection as follows: 
$$\nabla_\mathbf{w} \mathbf{v}= w^\alpha\frac{\partial v^\beta}{\partial x^\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}.$$
It would be interesting to know if this suffices to have a global diffeomorphism onto $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think the first condition is equivalent to having a flat Riemannian metric. For the second condition see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The torus can be written with an atlas of 9 charts (a 3 x 3 grid) with the transition functions all being translation.

Comment: Are you referring to the 2-dimensional torus? (P.S.: I guess that this should hold in any dimension, actually)

Comment: Yes, although the same claim (with more charts!) is almost certainly true in every dimension. Do you want me to write out the neighborhoods/transition functions?

Comment: If you added "simply connected" to your question, I think it might get more interesting, but I'm pretty sure that there are simply connected affine manifolds that aren't euclidean space. Bill Goldman spent a bunch of time on this stuff back in the 1980s, I think.

Comment: Don't bother with explicit transition functions, it is OK. Even the $\mathbb{S}^1$ example is fine for me. The only question I have is: is there any relationship between the Riemannian metric $g(v, w)=\sum_\alpha v^\alpha w^\alpha$ defined above and the actual Riemannian metric of the manifold (which is the one coming from the embedding into Euclidean space)? Take the case of $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: In my example, the two metrics are the same. And it seems to me that your metric $g$ is exactly the pullback, by the coordinate chart's differential, of the euclidean metric $g_e$ on $\mathbb R^2$ (or $\mathbb R^n$ in general)...but I wouldn't swear to that. Too many years since I really studied this stuff.

Comment: This is a bit weird, because if the metric were $g_{\alpha \beta}=\delta_{\alpha\beta}$, then $\mathbb{S}^1$ would be flat. Am I right?

Comment: I thought a bit about it and found that it is not weird at all, as $\mathbb{S}^1$ indeed is flat. Therefore, the product $\mathbb{T}^n=\mathbb{S}^1\times\dots\times\mathbb{S}^1$ is flat as well. I learned something from this discussion, thank you.

Comment: Almost makes you doubt the definition of "flat" for a moment, doesn't it? :)